# Android: when launching the camera app with camera photo intent, the user is required to make the photo twice

Tags: android, android-camera, pixel, android-camera-intent, image-capture

I see a strange behavior on two phones, when I just try to launch the camera app programmatically with an intent.

It works as it should on other phones (Samsung, Motorola...), but on two of my testing phones - Nexus 5x (Android 8) and Pixel (1) - Android (10) when the camera app is started, the user is required to make the photo twice before returning to my app with onActivityResult

The launching call is very simple, just for the test:

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentConstants.REQ_LAUNCH_CAMERA)
```

The camera app is started, it shows the camera screen with the "shooter" button, button is pressed, it shows the captured image with a check button for confirmation, and when it's pressed, confirmed, it doesn't exit.
Instead, it shows the camera screen again with the shooter button, wait for the user to make one more photo and to confirm it, and only after that the camera app is ending and is calling back onActivityResult

The intent is sent only once.
It's not happening on other phones (Samsung, Motorola, etc)

My guess is that this could be related to the camera app settings on the specific phone probably (but I don't see anything special there) or I need to add something in the intent (but I don't see anything)

I tried to add also

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false)
```

It doesn't change nothing on Pixel, but it causes an internal crash on Nexus 5X:

```
Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.google.android.apps.camera.shutterbutton.ShutterButton.performClick
com.google.android.GoogleCamera java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.google.android.apps.camera.shutterbutton.ShutterButton.performClick(PG:160)
```

I wouldn't worry much for the Nexus 5X, but the problem is that is happening on Pixel 1 as well, which means it may be problematic on Pixel 2,3,4 (didn't test those yet).

Anybody with a similar problem (and a potential solution), please let me know.

Comment: Most likely, this is simply a bug in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementation in the camera app that you are trying on that camera. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` seems not to get tested much by camera app developers.

Answer (score 0):

Mark (CommonsWare) is correct, it seems like a defect on google phones.

I found a workaround, instead

```
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentConstants.REQ_LAUNCH_CAMERA)
```

use a chooser:

```
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.camera_action_selection_title))

startActivityForResult(chooser, IntentConstants.REQ_LAUNCH_CAMERA)
```

That solves the problem.